# Issue with retrieving contact details

Tags: iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have tried to get all my iphone Contacts using [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts).
 It works on iPhone 5S but i cannot retrieve contacts in iPhone6+. This the code i am using

```
function onErrorContact(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
};

function onSuccessContact(contacts) {
    alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
}
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";
options.multiple = true;
var filter = ['displayName', 'name'];
navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccessContact, onErrorContact, options);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you give more details, what do you mean by "cannot retrieve" ?